# For Loops - Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm sure this is super simple, but I keep getting nothing. The instructions say:

"Write code that prints: firstNumber...2 1
Print a newline after each number. Ex: firstNumber = 3 outputs

```
3
2
1
```

Here's: the code:

```
public class ForLoops {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int firstNumber;
      int i;

      firstNumber = 3;

      for (i = 3; i <= 1; --i) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
   }
}
```

My thought process is since it wants me to count down from 3 to 1, I make i equal to 3, then it will count down for everything until i equals or is less than 1 with the --i.

If that makes sense.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Very unclear from what you have asked. Do you want suggestion on for loop written by you?

Comment: I read this 2 times to find out "what is the question". Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just want to see what I was doing wrong. The instructions ask me to count down from 3 to 1 using the for loop construct.

Comment: change this `for (i = 3; i <= 1; --i)` to `for (i = 3; i >= 1; --i)`

Comment: @Deadpool or even `for (i = firstNumber; i >= 1; --i)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the loop condition, that will never be `True`, Change the condition to this:

```
i >= 1
```

Because in this condition:

```
i <= 1
```

The current value of `i` is 3, and `3` is not smaller than (`<`) or equal to (`=`) `1`, so the condition will be `False` at the first place, and code inside `for` loop will never gets executed.

Also, you've created a variable `firstNumber`, which I believe is the starting  point of counter variable so you can change this line:

```
for (i = 3; i <= 1; --i)
```

to this:

```
for (i = firstNumber; i >= 1; --i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic here

```
for (i = 3; i <= 1; --i) {
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

is

```
a) start with i being three

b) if i <= 1
   then print
   decrement i

c) loop again
```

Obviously the loop will never be entered into

try

```
for (i = 3; i >= 1; --i) {
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write you code like:

```
public class ForLoops {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

       int firstNumber;
       int i;

       firstNumber = 3;

       for (i = firstNumber; i >= 1; --i) {
          System.out.println(i);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have simple mistake in for loop condition.

Shouldn't it be greater than or equal to (>=) as you are going in reverse direction.

change it to:

```
for (i = 3; i >= 1; --i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake seems to be, that you used a <= (smaller or equal) which is never true (3 can never be smaller or equal to 1). So you have to use a >=

And you can't have space in the name of your variable ( int first Numer; has to be int firstNumer;)

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(){
         int firstNumber;
         firstNumber = 3;

         for(int i = 3; i >= 1; i--){
              System.out.println(i);
         }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad spelling, but I am on my phone right now. I hope I could help you.

Comment: " instead of --i you have to use i--" doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score -2):

this is correc code:

```
   public class ForLoops {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      int firstNumber;
      int i;

      firstNumber = 3;

      i = firstNumber;   

      for (i = 3; i <= 1; --i) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not. Regardless of what `firstNumber` is the output will be the same.